# IIS 10: Windows 10 vs Windows Server 2016, Number of connections

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server

When I am looking for any information about IIS on the web, I find a gazillion links about IIS 7 and 8 but almost nothing about IIS 10, to the point I even question if it exists, even though I'm running it.

There are many posts about connection limits in the non server editions of windows; absolutely nothing regarding windows 10.

My question is:
Is there a limit to the number of simultaneous connections in Windows10/IIS 10 (so we should get Windows Server 2016)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On production you should always use server versions.

```
Windows 10      IIS v10.0
Home:           No IIS *We Think*
Pro:            simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows multiple sites *We Think*
Enterprise:     simultaneous request execution limit of 10, allows multiple sites *We Think*
Education:      unknown at this time
IoT Core:       unknown at this time
```

The source: http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm.
I run IIS 10 on Windows 10, and this limits are actualy true.