# .Net Core Web API scalability issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a .net core web api (end point A) which accept a post request with an ID in request body and in turn makes a GET request to another internal .net web api (end point B) which accepts that Id in header with some additional parameters in header and returns json data. End point B is tested using visual studio and scales well for around 2000 requests in 5 mins with average response time of .5 second which is good enough for us. However, when I test end point A, it performs poorly. Time to receive response from end point B gradually increases to up to 30 secs when it should be just around 500 ms.

Further, If I call another end point, lets say C, which accept post request, from my end point A code then I do not see any performance issue. Key parts of code are given below along with response time of call to end point B from end point A. There are no scalability issues in endpoint B. so, what could be reason for this behavior? There is proxy between A and B, but when I browse B url in browser manually, proxy authenticates and I am able to continue testing without any issues.

```
  private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = 500
    });

private async Task<object> GetResponse(string[] objectIds)
    {
        using var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://endpoint-B.com"),
        };

        httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("objectId", objectIds.FirstOrDefault());
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("Type", "Type1");

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Response received in " + sw.Elapsed.Seconds + " seconds and " + sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds +
                          " milliseconds");
        var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var newResponse = new {Content = content, SubsystemStatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode};
        return newResponse;

    }
```

Results on console:

[image: console progress -1]

[image: Console progress-2]

[image: Console progress-2]

[image: Load test settings for end point A]

Comment: `However, when I test end point A, it performs poorly.` How _specifically_ are you testing it? Under what kind of load?

Comment: `Time to receive response from end point B gradually increases to up to 30 secs when it should be just around 500 ms.` Have you profiled it end to end to identify where the bottleneck is occurring (e.g. logging various points in endpoint A and B to narrow down where the 30 seconds is being spent)?

Comment: @mjwills OS is Windows..for all servers

Comment: @mjwills how should I profile it? I see that response is received so late..like 30 secs. i.e await ends after 30 secs

Comment: @mjwillis I am testing using visual studio load test tool. My settings for loadtest for end point A is same as end point B. Purpose of end point is A is to take json data from endpoint B and transform it and return to client

Comment: How large is the payload being returned from endpoint B?

Comment: @mjwills don't you think current stopwatch log shows that await client.SendAsync(httpRequest)  is taking all the time? it starts before it and measured after it

Comment: @mjwills sorry, I am trying to find out how to put extra logging "inside" what httpclient is doing.  payload is around 50KB. Current code I have given (end point A) is running on my local machine which is windows 10. end point B is on windows server, version of  which I can figure out if needed. It's "like production" as we are doing UAT so it has good memory and cpu.

Comment: @mjwills Windows 10 enterprise

Comment: @mjwills I have added load test config image in post. I also check where response is valid or not in load test. some responses are invalid i.e they contain null fields for all objects. End point B never sends null fields for any object when load tested using same load test profile. btw, I might go sleep in few mins and reply after I wake up. too sleepy :)

Comment: Is it running on IIS? How _specifically_ is A hosted?

Comment: Have a squiz at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672344/34092 . You are likely being bottlenecked by the 10 connection limit.

Comment: @mjwills A is hosted by kestrel on local machine right now. Loadtesting end point B on my local machine does not show scalability issues so I don't think connection limit is coming in to picture. How does loadtester able to loadtest B if it has connection limit? it shows avg response time of .6 sec. but when I load test end point B "through" my api end point A, using code I gave in question, you can see it performs poorly. Also, if I change my code to connect to end point C which uses POST, then no scalability issues again. End point C is on same server as end point B.

Comment: How fast is end point C vs end point B? What is the size of the payload from end point C? I think you need to share your [mcve] for B and C so we can compare the two.